# WriteAllBytes - Access to the path is denied

Tags: c#, .net

I have pdf file as byte array inside myObject.PdfFile and I'm trying to save this inside hdd using write all bytes

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\a.pdf", myObject.PdfFile);
```

using this I'm getting following exception

> {"Access to the path 'C:\a.pdf' is denied."}

Should I first create a.pdf file and then to use or I'm missing something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is to be expected. Standard user does not have rights to create files at the root of the system volume. Save the file somewhere else where you do have rights. For instance, somewhere under the user profile.